# c# use combobox for copy folder from C drive to removable drive

Tags: c#, combobox, copy

I try to use combobox for copy folder from C:\folderX\folderY drive to removable drive :\folderName\
the combobox choose destination drive to copy the files to.
My code so far

```
using System.IO;
namespace OptimaBackup
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            getdrive();
        }
        private void getdrive()

        {
            string[] driv = Directory.GetLogicalDrives();
            foreach (string item in driv)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(item.ToString());
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string getinfo = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            DriveInfo drinfo = new DriveInfo(getinfo);
            string drivety = drinfo.DriveType.ToString(); //this for copy to usb drive
            {

                MessageBox.Show(" The File is copy To " );

            }
        }

        // this is for copy from usb drive to C drive
        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a question to ask?

Comment: Thanks Steve, my code works fine, I need to know what to write after this code string -  drivety = drinfo.DriveType.ToString();  - for complit this code for copy folder from folder my C:\ folder to the Usb Drive folder

Comment: The [File class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) has a method that allows you to copy a file from a place to another ([File.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx)). Try to use it and if you have problems update this question with the new code